# Imported module is not defined

Tags: node.js, typescript

Learning nodejs + typescript, while met such situation:

Situation:

**folder1/file1.ts**

```
    export module ModuleFactory{
         export function do(){
              return new SomeClass();
         }
    }
```

**folder2/file2.ts**

```
    import {ModelFactory} from "../folder1/file1";

    class Usage{
      constructor(){
          this.rez = ModelFactory.do();
      }
    }
```

Problem is that I get `rez` undefined. And during debug, I noticed that ModelFactory throws: `ReferenceError: ModelFactory is not defined`.

Where is the problem?

Comment: You're exporting `ModuleFactory` but importing `ModelFactory`?

Comment: just mistype, during example code witing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do it like this:

**folder1/file1.ts**

```
export function do(){
  return new SomeClass();
}
```

**folder2/file2.ts**

```
import * as ModuleFactory from '../folder1/file1';

class Usage{
  constructor(){
    this.rez = ModuleFactory.do();
  }
}
```